# Transfer original gmail messages only to google sheets and not replies

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

I have the following script which searches my gmail for a certain query and then imports it to google sheets. It seems to work but it also imports replies to the original email which I don't want to include. Is there a way I can modify my script so that it shows the original email only and not any replies that others may have added? Many thanks.

```
var SEARCH_QUERY = "newer_than:1d from:contactcentrequeries AND subject:feedback";

/*
 Credit: Alexander Ivanov
 https://gist.github.com/contributorpw/70e04a67f1f5fd96a708
*/

function getEmails_(q) {
    var emails = [];
    var threads = GmailApp.search(q);
    for (var i in threads) {
        var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j in msgs) {
             emails.push([msgs[j].getBody().replace(/<.+?>/g, '\n')
                .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, '').replace(/^\s*/gm, '').replace(/\s*\n/gm, '\n')
            ]);
        }
    }
    return emails;
}

function appendData_(sheet, array2d) {
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, array2d.length, array2d[0].length).setValues(array2d);
}

function saveEmails() {
    var array2d = getEmails_(SEARCH_QUERY);
    if (array2d) {
        appendData_(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), array2d);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you have provided it seems that the issue is related to how you are calling the `msgs` variable. More precisely, the `threads[i].getMessages();` line of code will retrieve **all the messages** for the `thread i`. If you want to get **only the first message** of the thread - which is essentially the original email, you should simply use `msgs[0]` instead of another `for` loop.

Therefore, your code should look something like this:

```
for (var i in threads) {
  var msgs = threads[i].getMessages();
  emails.push([
    msgs[0]
      .getBody()
      .replace(/<.+?>/g, "\n")
      .replace(/^\s*\n/gm, "")
      .replace(/^\s*/gm, "")
      .replace(/\s*\n/gm, "\n")
  ]);
}
```

**Reference**

- [GmailThread Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-thread);
- [GmailApp Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app).

Comment: I just want to add that your explanation really helped, I now know what I'm looking at properly!

Comment: @NeilStopforth, I am really glad that my solution was of help to you! Cheers :)